# In mysql, the show databases; command doesn't list all of my databases

Tags: mysql

I can access all of my databases with HeidiSQL, but if I go to the mysql.exe window and use show databases; only 2 of them show up out of 11. These are all databases on 127.0.0.1. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Random stab in the dark: Could it be a permissions issue? Are you logging into HeidiSQL as the same MySQL user as when you launch `mysql.exe`?

Comment: I'm logging in with the username root for HeidiSQL. When I'm using mysql, I'm just typing showdatabases;

Comment: How are you launching MySQL? Are you just typing `mysql` at a command prompt? If so, try typing `mysql --user=root` instead.

Comment: I'm opening the mysql.exe and typing in commands there. This is all from windows 7. If I try typing mysql --user=root -p it tells me 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: *How* are you "opening the mysql.exe"? Is are you double-clicking on an shortcut-icon somewhere? If so, try right-clicking on that, go the "Shorcut" tab, and tell me what you see in the "Target" field.

Comment: I'm double clicking the actual mysql.exe. The path to that is c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe

Comment: O.K., so try opening a command prompt and typing `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=root`.

Comment: it says error 1045 (28000) "access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)   I added --password=mypass and it brought me to the mysql>

Comment: that brought me to the mysql> and it's showing all of them when I use show databases; now. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm trying to get a .sql file to load into one of the databases. Do you know the command for that? I've tried mysql --user=root --password=mypass dbName < fileName.sql but that just gives makes a new line and doesn't do anything.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post this as an answer, then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're logging into HeidiSQL as `root`, so it's showing you all databases, but you're logging into `mysql.exe` as the current Windows user (since that's the default), so it's only showing you the databases that that user can see. If you run `mysql.exe` with `--user=root --password=...`, it will show you all databases.

Answer (score 17):

in my case, `SHOW DATABASES` or `SHOW DATABASES;` didn't work.

what worked is:

```
show databases;
```

Comment: This was my issue. Needed lowercase and the semi-colon.

Comment: This was also my problem. Although for me only the semicolon mattered - upper and lowercase both work.

Answer (score 5):

**I am using Oracle mySql**

```
mysql> show databases;
```

This command show all databases in your SQL server

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to log in using your username and password before you issue show databases command on cmd. If you request show databases without this, cmd will only show you default databases. your username and password(optional if you username is root) grant you the needed access to the databases.  This is my experience and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a screen session, that can also truncate your results. Just thought I'd throw that out there since that's what my issue was that led me here ---

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem It seems that in never version you need to add
semicolon at the end of the command.

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Work fine for me with lowercase and uppercase letters.