# MySQL: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sequel

I'm having a problem with MySQL on Mac Os - this also includes the Sequel Pro. Today I installed the newest version of MySQL on my computer. The situation is like this:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> SHOW DATABASES
```

The output is this

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE' at line 1

So I tried to create a database through Sequel Pro. I have created a database called 'test'.  But it doesn't show any database at Sequel Pro. I tried `mysql> SHOW DATABASE;` at my terminal again and it's still the same error.

After that I tried `mysql> USE test;` - it work, but then `mysql> show tables;` it shows

> ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist.

Does anybody know where the problem may be?

Comment: The first command is plural: `SHOW DATABASES;` ... without the trailing `S`, I see the same error message. I'm not sure about the 2nd error.

Comment: Thank's for answer, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: If you do not need any data: Uninstall MySQL, make sure to also delete the data directory, and then reinstall cleanly.

Comment: I did it. To be sure I reinstall my computer just to be sure everything is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In  mysql the command is:

Show DATABASES;

The DATABASES command is case sensitive

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for that mistake. Even when I tried `Show DATABASES` it gives me this error: `ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist`

Comment: Does this help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558029/in-mysql-the-show-databases-command-doesnt-list-all-of-my-databases

Comment: Thank's for advice. I know that as user 'root' I don't have all permissions I think that can be my problem. I tried to add permission through this code `update mysql.user set plugin="mysql_native_password"` and it didn't work still